# Why do Disk utility and Gparted show different information for the same hdd(s)?

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

Gparted and Disks utility give me different sizes for my hard drive and its partitions. Is there a reason, for both programs, to list different information or is it an error?

**GParted & Terminal output:** `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

> dev/sda = 298.1 Gib
>    /dev/sda3 = 191.40 GiB
>    /dev/sda4 = 92 GiB
>    /dev/sda5 = 88.40 GiB
>    /dev/sda6 = 3.60 GiB

**Disks Utility output**

> dev/sdb = 320 Gib
>     /dev/sda3 = 206 GiB
>     /dev/sda4 = 99 GiB
>     /dev/sda5 = 95 GiB
>     /dev/sda6 = 3.9 GiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result shown by `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` performs calculations using the *binary prefix* i.e. multiples of *1024* (which is 2<sup>10</sup>). So *500107862016 bytes* would be equal to *465.76 GB* or approximately *466 GB*. (You can use `-b` switch to print in bytes instead of human readable as `sudo lsblk -b -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`.)

```
Calculation:

500107862016 bytes = (500107862016 / (1024 ^ 3)) GB = 465.76 GB
```

While Disks Utility uses decimal prefix for calculation so expressed as multiples of *1000*. So *500107862016 bytes* here would mean *500.11 GB or 500 GB* approx.

```
Calculation:

500107862016 bytes = (500107862016 / (1000 ^ 3)) GB = 500.11 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I would assume that the terminal command is giving you the actual size of a partition, while gparted is giving you the size available using the current allocation size settings. When you format a partition the filesystem uses an allocation size (also called cluster size), the larger the size the less storage you get due to inefficient usage, but you can get faster write speeds as a tradeoff when writing large files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this for a fact, but I would assume that Disk Utility is telling you the actual size, and Gparted is telling you the functioning size, since the filesystem and partition table take some room. Allocation sizes aren't a factor, because they don't take up space, it's merely a setting.